# create dynamic ImageViews during runtime on android

Tags: android, xml, dynamic, imageview

I got a bit of a problem with an app I'm building in Android. Previously we were showing 3 images in a LinearLayout, but now the amount of images has to vary. This means I have to make ImageViews during runtime, depending on how many I receive from the DB. This is how the ImageViews are defined right now:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/afbeelding1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:padding="1dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/afbeelding2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:padding="1dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/afbeelding3"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:padding="1dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

These ImageViews are filled at runtime, something I'll do with the new style as well. Does anybody know how I can achieve this? I'd also like to implement an OnClickListener on the ImageViews, so when you click on it, they get bigger.

Comment: How about a ListView?

Comment: ah suppose that could work. A ListView with every item being an ImageView?

Comment: yes,  ListView + SimpleCursorAdapter